# Generating button for each row of record that will display row's full information

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database set up with several records and a table that displays each row of the record. For each row of the table, the only information that are displayed are the 'name', 'program' and 'course' taken from 'personal' and 'faculty' tables. I'm trying to add a button on each row that will retrieve and show all information regarding that specific row. here are my codes

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, Full_Name, Program, Course FROM personal, faculty";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo  . $row["id"].  . $row["Full_Name"] . 
. $row["Program"]. $row["Course"]. ;
 }

 } else { echo "0 results"; }
 $conn->close();
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it you're asking. If it helps please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<a href` link to each ID as it is output. I made up a name for the program to be called since you didn't tell us what it is.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  '<a href="showdetails.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' .
            $row['id'] . '</a>' .
            $row['Full_Name']   .
            $row['Program']     .
            $row['Course'];
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean by program? Is it the php page where I put the code in?

Comment: In my example `showdetails.php` is what would be used to show the details of a row. It is something you would create.